# Drag and Drop extension in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, drag-and-drop, swt

I am implementing the drag and drop feature in an Eclipse based product that we use. Essentially we are extending the behavior to add our own.

- I have created a custom view using Eclipse templates. It has also rendered me a tree. Now, after registering and implementing the drag and drop listeners, I am able to drag/drop components of this view only. Our original intention was to drag/drop components from other already-in-place views to this view. But I am not able to drag them to my custom view.
- I would like to know if there is anything else that needs to be done here.

  1. There is an existing UI component, say a panel, which has a TREE structure. I am adding a new panel which would also be having a TREE structure. I finally want to drag items from first UI to second [ new ] UI.
  2. Simply adding a drop listener at my target UI [new UI] is not allowing me to drag files out of the first UI panel.

----------------RESOLVED TILL HERE----------------

I have used made sure that I was using the same custom transfer type at both the Drag Source and at the Drop Target. With this I was able to drag components from my new panel to that existing panel and vice versa. I however have 2 questions.

1. Is it really a requirement that one has to use the same type of transfer type at both the drag source and drop target?.
2. An interesting scenario is in place with our product. We are able to drag files from windows explorer and drop them into our product. So, how is this achieved?. I mean if the above point 1 holds true, then how could windows system implement the custom transfer mode that our product has implemented? [ I know W does not do so...probably it implements some generic transfer stuff.

Comment: Have you read http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=523

Comment: I have been trying to post since the other day that I have got a resolution for this one..but due to bad network at my end, I could not connect properly. Please find my response edited to my OP.
Thanks BTW Tonny and I did refer to that one :).